# Plotting a 3D piecewise function

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, special-functions

I would like to plot the following function:

```
    f[x_, y_] := -1/(4 Pi) NIntegrate[
   Sin[a] (3 x^2 y^2 Cos[a]^2/((y^2 Cos[b]^2 + x^2 Sin[b]^2) Sin[a]^2 + 
          x^2 y^2 Cos[a]^2) - 1), {a, 0, Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

using to that its closed form expression:

```
    f1[x_, y_] := 
 1 - (3*x*y)/(1 - x^2)^(3/2)*(
   EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)] - 
    EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)])/((
   1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2))
```

for $x<y<1$, and

```
f2[x_, y_] := (1 + 2*x^2)/(
  1 - x^2) + (
   3*x*y)/((y^2 - 1)^(
    1/2)*(x^2 - 1))*(EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[y^2 - 1]/y], (y^2 - x^2)/(
     y^2 - 1)])
```

for $x\geq y \geq 1$. Here is my attempt:

```
p1 = Plot3D[f1[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x < y]]

p2 = Plot3D[f2[x, y], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10},RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x >= y]]

Show[p1, p2]
```

But unfortunately, $$\mbox{Plot[f[x,y]}\neq \mbox{Show[p1,p2]]}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `Plot3D[]` then you can do it like this

```
f1[x_, y_] := 
 If[x <= y <= 1, 
  1 - (3*x*y)/(1 - x^2)^(3/2)*(EllipticF[
        ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)] - 
       EllipticE[
        ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)])/((1 - y^2)/(1 - 
         x^2))]

f2[x_, y_] := 
 If[x >= y >= 
   1, (1 + 2*x^2)/(1 - 
      x^2) + (3*x*y)/((y^2 - 1)^(1/2)*(x^2 - 1))*(EllipticE[
      ArcSin[Sqrt[y^2 - 1]/y], (y^2 - x^2)/(y^2 - 1)])]
Plot3D[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: fig1]

To get a figure 4.2 from the [article](https://d-nb.info/1013436156/34) we set

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 1 + 3*x*y*
   Re[(EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)] - 
        EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)])/(1 - 
        y^2)/Sqrt[1 - x^2]]

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors",Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Thank you. But this is not the plot I'm looking for. The plot of this function can be found in Figure 4.2 [here](https://d-nb.info/1013436156/34). The closed expression is found in appendix A.

Comment: Then you made a mistake in the definition, since in this article in Fig. 4.2 the real part of the function (4.34) is shown.

Comment: Thank you again. But what about the two blank lines?

Comment: These are the lines on which `x=1`, `y=1`. You can make them invisible using the option `Exclusions -> None`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!

Comment: @DineshShankar You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: **the piecewise expression is completely unnecessary in *Mathematica***. The [dissertation](https://d-nb.info/1013436156/34) you link to assumes (usually rightly) that the parameter $m$ in the elliptic integrals involved need to be in the interval $[0,1]$. (Once again, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659) is a pointed reminder of the different argument conventions used for elliptic integrals.) That is usually a requirement for other software, but not for *Mathematica*. Thus (using the expression for `f2`):

```
Plot3D[(2 x^2 + 1)/(1 - x^2) +
       (3 x y EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[y^2 - 1]/y], (y^2 - x^2)/(y^2 - 1)])/
       ((x^2 - 1) Sqrt[y^2 - 1]), {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: the surface]

---

### Extra credit

I am normally averse towards self-promotion, but it seems justified in this case. I had recently written [a *Mathematica* package](https://github.com/tpfto/Carlson) for evaluating a different set of elliptic integrals called the [Carlson integrals](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19#PT3). These functions usually need one more argument than might be thought to be necessary in their representations, but this little bit of flexibility pays off in them having easier to manipulate identities.

Let's assume you have already downloaded and installed the package:

```
<<Carlson`
```

We will use the Carlson integrals to show that the expressions for `f1` and `f2` are in fact the same. Unfortunately, the package does not *yet* (**;)**) support simplification identities, so we are going to get a little help from the DLMF along the way.

```
Remove[f1, f2];

f1 = 1 - (3 x y (-EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)] +
     EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 - x^2]], (1 - y^2)/(1 - x^2)]))/(Sqrt[1 - x^2] (1 - y^2));

f2 = (2 x^2 + 1)/(1 - x^2) + (3 x y EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[y^2 - 1]/y],
                              (y^2 - x^2)/(y^2 - 1)])/((x^2 - 1) Sqrt[y^2 - 1]);
```

The first thing to do is to use the [conversion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.25.E5) [identities](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.25.E9) to convert the Legendre-Jacobi integrals to Carlson integrals. Applied to `f1`:

```
f1 /. {EllipticF[ϕ_, m_] :> Sin[ϕ] CarlsonRF[Cos[ϕ]^2, 1 - m Sin[ϕ]^2, 1], 
       EllipticE[ϕ_, m_] :> Sin[ϕ] CarlsonRF[Cos[ϕ]^2, 1 - m Sin[ϕ]^2, 1] - 
       m/3 Sin[ϕ]^3 CarlsonRD[Cos[ϕ]^2, 1 - m Sin[ϕ]^2, 1]} // Simplify
   1 - x y CarlsonRD[x^2, y^2, 1]
```

and we immediately get a wonderfully simple expression compared to the original mess: $1-xy\, R_D\left(x^2,y^2,1\right)$. Let's try it on the other one:

```
f2a = f2 /. EllipticE[ϕ_, m_] :> Sin[ϕ] CarlsonRF[Cos[ϕ]^2, 1 - m Sin[ϕ]^2, 1] - 
            m/3 Sin[ϕ]^3 CarlsonRD[Cos[ϕ]^2, 1 - m Sin[ϕ]^2, 1] // Simplify
   ((x^3 - x y^2) CarlsonRD[1/y^2, x^2/y^2, 1] +
    y^2 (-1 - 2 x^2 + 3 x CarlsonRF[1, 1/y^2, x^2/y^2]))/((-1 + x^2) y^2)
```

A bit messy. But again, the good thing about Carlson integrals is that they are easier to manipulate. First, let's use the [homogeneity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.20.E1) [identities](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.20.E18):

```
f2b = f2a /. {CarlsonRD[u_, v_, w_] :> y^3 CarlsonRD[y^2 u, y^2 v, y^2 w], 
              CarlsonRF[u_, v_, w_] :> y CarlsonRF[y^2 u, y^2 v, y^2 w]} // Simplify
   (-1 - 2 x^2 + x y (x^2 - y^2) CarlsonRD[1, x^2, y^2] + 
    3 x y CarlsonRF[1, x^2, y^2])/(-1 + x^2)
```

We are almost, but not quite there. The simple expression obtained earlier has `CarlsonRD[x^2, y^2, 1]`, while this has `CarlsonRD[1, x^2, y^2]` (recall that `CarlsonRD[]` is only symmetric in its first two arguments, `CarlsonRD[x, y, z] == CarlsonRD[y, x, z]`). Thus, we need the [interchange identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.21.E7):

```
f2c = f2b /. CarlsonRD[x_, y_, z_] :> (3 CarlsonRF[x, y, z] - (x - y) CarlsonRD[y, z, x] -
                                       3 Sqrt[y]/(Sqrt[x] Sqrt[z]))/(z - y) // Simplify
   -((y + 2 x^2 y - 3 x Sqrt[x^2] Sqrt[y^2] +
     x (-1 + x^2) y^2 CarlsonRD[x^2, y^2, 1])/((-1 + x^2) y))
```

Finally, since we are assuming nonnegative values of `x` and `y`:

```
f2c // PowerExpand // Simplify
   1 - x y CarlsonRD[x^2, y^2, 1]
```

*et voilà*!

Evaluating `Plot3D[1 - x y CarlsonRD[x^2, y^2, 1], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]` should yield the same plot as above.